# Allow outgoing traffic using DOCKER-USER chain iptables

Tags: docker, iptables

I am using docker chain documented here https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/ to block incoming traffic from public interface except from one IP.

```sh
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eno1 ! -s X.X.X.X -j DROP
```

The side effect of this is that outgoing traffic from container to the rest of the world is also dropped. How to block incoming and allow outgoing using DOCKER-USER chain or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found something that works in my case. It's the combinasion of many others answere that wasn't working...

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eno1 ! -s X.X.X.X -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 25562:25570 --ctdir ORIGINAL -j DROP
```